# Split list and make sum from sublist?

Tags: haskell, numbers, int

im searching for a solution for my Haskell class.

I have a list of numbers and i need to return SUM for every part of list. Parts are divided by 0. I need to use FOLDL function.

Example:
initial list: [1,2,3,0,3,4,0,5,2,1]
sublist [[1,2,3],[3,4],[5,2,1]]
result [6,7,7]

I have a function for finding 0 in initial list:

```
findPos list = [index+1 | (index, e) <- zip [0..] list, e == 0]
```

(returns [4,6] for initial list from example)

and function for making SUM with FOLDL:

```
sumList list = foldl (+) 0 list
```

But I completely failed to put it together :/

---- MY SOLUTION 
In the end I found something completely different that you guys suggested. 
Took me whole day to make it :/

```
groups :: [Int] -> [Int]
groups list = [sum x | x <- makelist list]

makelist :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
makelist xs = reverse (foldl (\acc x -> zero x acc) [[]] xs)  

zero :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
zero x acc | x == 0 = addnewtolist acc
           | otherwise = addtolist x acc

addtolist :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
addtolist i listlist = (i : (head listlist)) : (drop 1 listlist)

addnewtolist :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
addnewtolist listlist = [] : listlist
```

Comment: I think `result` should be `[6,7,8]` instead of `[6,7,7]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've completed the problem on your own, I am showing you a slightly less verbose version.  `Foldr` seems better in my opinion to this problem*, but because you asked for `foldl` I will show you my solution using both functions.

Also, your example appears to be incorrect, the sum of [5,2,1] is 8, not 7.

The `foldr` version.

```hs
makelist' l = foldr (\x (n:ns) -> if x == 0 then 0:(n:ns) else (x + n):ns) [0] l
```

In this version, we traverse the list, if the current element (x) is a 0, we add a new element to the accumulator list (n:ns). Otherwise, we add the value of the current element to the value of the front element of the accumulator, and replace the front value of the accumulator with this value.

Step by step:

1. `acc = [0], x = 1. Result is [0+1]`
2. `acc = [1], x = 2. Result is [1+2]`
3. `acc = [3], x = 5. Result is [3+5]`
4. `acc = [8], x = 0. Result is 0:[8]`
5. `acc = [0,8], x = 4. Result is [0+4,8]`
6. `acc = [4,8], x = 3. Result is [4+3,8]`
7. `acc = [7,8], x = 0. Result is 0:[7,8]`
8. `acc = [0,7,8], x = 3. Result is [0+3,7,8]`
9. `acc = [3,7,8], x = 2. Result is [3+2,7,8]`
10. `acc = [5,7,8], x = 1. Result is [5+1,7,8] = [6,7,8]`

There you have it!

And the `foldl` version. Works similarly as above, but produces a reversed list, hence the use of reverse at the beginning of this function to unreverse the list.

```hs
makelist l = reverse $ foldl (\(n:ns) x -> if x == 0 then 0:(n:ns) else (x + n):ns) [0] l
```

*Folding the list from the right allows the cons (:) function to be used naturally, using my method with a left fold produces a reversed list. (There is likely a simpler way to do the left fold version that I did not think of that eliminates this triviality.)

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to give you some hints, rather than a complete solution, since this sounds like it may be a homework assignment.

I like the breakdown of steps you've suggested. For the first step (going from a list of numbers with zero markers to a list of lists), I suggest doing an explicit recursion; try this for a template:

```
splits []     = {- ... -}
splits (0:xs) = {- ... -}
splits (x:xs) = {- ... -}
```

You can also abuse [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3agroupBy) if you're careful.

For the second step, it looks like you're almost there; the last step you need is to take a look at the [`map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap) function, which takes a normal function and runs it on each element of a list.

As a bonus exercise, you might want to think about how you might do the whole thing in one shot as a single fold. It's possible -- and even not too difficult, if you track through what the types of the various arguments to `foldr`/`foldl` would have to be!

**Additions since the question changed:**

Since it looks like you've worked out a solution, I now feel comfortable giving some spoilers. =)

I suggested two possible implementations; one that goes step-by-step, as you suggested, and another that goes all at once. The step-by-step one could look like this:

```
splits []     = []
splits (0:xs) = [] : splits xs
splits (x:xs) = case splits xs of
    []       -> [[x]]
    (ys:yss) -> ((x:ys):yss)

groups' = map sum . splits
```

Or like this:

```
splits' = groupBy (\x y -> y /= 0)
groups'' = map sum . splits'
```

The all-at-once version might look like this:

```
accumulate 0 xs     = 0:xs
accumulate n (x:xs) = (n+x):xs

groups''' = foldr accumulate [0]
```

To check that you understand these, here are a few exercises you might like to try:

- What do `splits` and `splits'` do with `[1,2,3,0,4,5]`? `[1,2,0,3,4,0]`? `[0]`? `[]`? Check your predictions in ghci.
- Predict what each of the four versions of `groups` (including yours) output for inputs like `[]` or `[1,2,0,3,4,0]`, and then test your prediction in ghci.
- Modify `groups'''` to exhibit the behavior of one of the other implementations.
- Modify `groups'''` to use `foldl` instead of `foldr`.

Comment: And you can use the split package from Hackage and `splitOn [0]` if this is not homework.

Comment: Hi, thank you for help :) Sadly it wasnt very helpfull for me. I guest that I needed "example for dummies". Im really new to haskell so I had problems like: "how to add something to first list in list" and "how to write types" etc.. anyway, can you please write solution you suggested? Im interested how it should be :)

Comment: @DanielWagner I like how much more readable your final version is with the helper function than mine. Good solution!

Answer (score 1):

As you already solved it, another version:

```
subListSums list = reverse $ foldl subSum [0] list where
   subSum xs 0 = 0 : xs
   subSum (x:xs) n = (x+n) : xs
```

<strike>(Assuming that you have only non-negative numbers in the list)</strike>

Comment: If the numbers of a group would sum up to zero, this zero would be "overwritten" by the next group, so this sum wouldn't appear in the final list.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood your own code! No part of your code checks whether the current running sum is equal to `0`; moreover, on a more empirical level, `subListSums [2,-2,0,2,-2]` seems to do the right thing in ghci.