# Sum of separated elements in a list

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split list and make sum from sublist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775072/split-list-and-make-sum-from-sublist)

Im trying to solve this problem.
I need to do a sum of elements from a list which are separated from each other only with "0".
So for example I can have something like this as input: [1,2,3,0,3,4,0,2,1]
and the output should be [6,7,3].

So far I managed to do something like this:

```
cut (x:xs) | x > 0 = x : (cut xs)
       | otherwise = []

first  (xs) = ( (foldl (+) 0 (cut          (xs)))   ) : []
second (xs) = ( (foldl (+) 0 (cut (reverse (xs))))  ) : []

test (xs) = first(xs) ++ second(xs)
```

Problem is that this only works with only 1 instance of "0" in my list.

I was trying to solve this by editing my cut function:

```
cut [] = []
cut (x:xs) | x > 0 = foldl (+) 0 ( x : cut xs) : []
       | x == 0 = (cut xs)
```

But I cant figure out how to adjust it, so it will separate the sums. Right now it just throws the sum of all the elements as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For homework you should definitely follow dave's answer. However, here is a more advanced solution, employing `groupBy` as poor man's `split`:

```
import Data.List (groupBy)

map sum $ groupBy (const (/=0)) list
```

This might look cute, but note that there are still the zeros at the beginning of the sub-lists present, so you can't use this solution without changes if that matters (e.g if you need products instead of sums)

**[Explanation]**

`groupBy` looks if the first element of the current group "fits together" with the current element of the list. In that case the current element will be added to the group, else a new group starts. E.g.

```
groupBy (\x y -> x `mod` y == 0) [81,3,9,25,5]
--[[81,3,9],[25,5]]
```

Here the test ist successful for `81 'mod' 3` and `81 'mod' 9`, but not for `81 'mod' 25`, which starts a new group. Again, `25 'mod' 5` is successful.

But in our case all elements "fit" in the current group as long as they are not 0, so we don't even have to look at the first element. And if a 0 is found, a new group is started.

`const (/=0)` means just `\_ y -> y /= 0`, so regardless what the first argument is, it just tests that the second element isn't 0. To see why, look at the definition:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const a _ =  a
```

Now our lambda can be written as

```
\x y -> const (/= 0) x y
```

As from the `const` call only the first of the two arguments "survives", we have

```
\x y -> (/= 0) y
```

... or...

```
\_ y -> y /= 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect solution for me since I need to use foldl (+) 0. So i have it like this: map (foldl (+) 0) (groupBy ... [])

Answer (score 5):

You can divide your problem into two tasks

1. Split a list into parts on zeros.
2. Sum parts.

For the first task we have [`Data.List.Split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.1.4.2) module which exports [`splitOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.4.2/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asplitOn) function.
It does precisely what we need:

```
> splitOn [1] [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0]
[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0]]
```

For the second task there is well-known [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3amap)-function which applies a function to the each element of the list.
In our case this function is [`sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3asum):

```
> map sum [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[6,15,24]
```

So:

```
> :m +Data.List.Split
> map sum . splitOn [0] $ [1,2,3,0,3,4,0,2,1] 
[6,7,3]
```

Comment: @mtzero If it isn't a real problem you should tag your question as homework.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're unable to install to install the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package and use Data.List.Split as Matvey suggests, you can still use the general approach:

1. Split the weird list with `0` separators into a more conventional list of lists.
2. Sum each list.

So

```
yourFunction = map sum . split
```

Now we have to write `split`.

```
split :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
```

In general, when we want to pull a list apart to synthesise something new, we need to use a fold.

```
split = foldr cons nil where
```

`nil` here should be whatever you want `split []` to be.

```
    nil = --TODO: exercise for you; clue: NOT []
```

`cons` meanwhile combines one of your numbers, with the answer from the previous step of the fold. Obviously, you'll need to do different things depending on whether or not the number is `0`.

```
    cons 0 xss        = --TODO
    cons x (xs : xss) = --TODO; why will this pattern match never fail?
```